# use of "Execute Javascript" Selenium2Library to retrieve value

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Using the below script to retrieve value by passing WebElement as argument in javascript:

```
${elem}=Get WebElement    name=productField
${value}=Execute Javascript    return document.arguments[0].value,'${elem}'; 
Log To Console    ${value}
```

Seeing the below error:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

In the [SeleniumLibrary documentation](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Text) there are two keywords that useful in this situation: `Get Text` and `Get Value`. Both take your identifier as input and return the desired text.

```
${text}=     Get Text     name=productField
${value}=    Get Value    name=productField
```

So, there is no need to use javascript for this.

Comment: Unable to retrieve values using the above two Keywords. Looks like I need to use javascript.

Comment: Can you update your question with a simplified HTML DOM with the element you want to fetch the data from? Then we have something concrete to work with.